# Нужно ли тире между словами "фронтально" и "развитой"?

Tags: орфография

Заголовок статьи: "Преимущества и недостатки фронтально развитой архитектурной композиции".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Здесь используется раздельное написание наречия и прилагательного: развитая (как? каким образом?) фронтально.

Для дефисного написания должно быть соответствие: фронтальная развитая композиция, но такого соответствия нет. Слитное написание применяется для терминов, но такого термина, очевидно, не существует.

**Для справок:** Во фронтальной композиции элементы архитектурной формы расположены в пространстве таким образом, что этот тип композиции характеризуется развитием по двум координатам, горизонтальной и вертикальной. Глубинная координата является подчиненной.

Answer (score 1):

Тире точно не нужно. Наверно, вы имели в виду дефис, но и он не нужен, потому что можно задать вопрос: композиция развита как? Фронтально. А через дефис пишутся прилагательные, выражающие разные признаки существительного и взаимодополняющие друг друга, а не подчинённые друг другу.

Comment: Имеется в виду «более фронтальная, чем объёмная», как, например, у протяжённых фасадов Лувра или ГУМа.

Comment: Понятно, shampar, спасибо! Тогда уберу второй абзац.